# How did space travel spread throughout the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

By the time of the *Star Wars* films almost every species has access to space travel and faster-than-light technology. Has it ever been mentioned where this came from, did a specific species go out and teach other species it came across, did several species discover it at around the same time?

Comment: How did space travel spread through the galaxy? Probably via space travel.

Comment: Probably the same way that automobile travel has spread on Earth.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, it was a long time ago...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Canon

The [purrgil](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Purrgil) were whale-like creatures that were naturally capable of entering hyperspace, and observation of these creatures inspired the development of the first hyperdrives. However, it's not clear exactly who developed the first hyperdrives or how the technology spread throughout the galaxy. It's likely the case that one or possibly a few civilizations invented the hyperdrive and then spread the technology to other civilizations as they used it to explore the galaxy.

#### Legends

The species most responsible for the spread of faster-than-light travel was probably the [Rakata](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata#History). Their hyperdrives were Force-powered and inspired by the [Kwa species](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kwa), but in creating their [Infinite Empire](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata#The_Infinite_Empire) the Rakata conquered many of the most important worlds of the galaxy (such as Coruscant, Corellia, the Wookiee homeworld of Kashyyyk, Tatooine, Dantooine, Manaan, etc.). When the Infinite Empire fell, some of the subject species were able to modify the Rakatan hyperdrive so that it no longer required the Force to operate. Space travel as we know it from the *Star Wars* films was possible at this point with star systems' connections from the fallen Infinite Empire and the means to travel faster-than-light and without the Force.

Answer (score 6):

Since the Old Republic is said to have existed for a thousand generations, the invention of space travel/FTL should be so far in the past that probably no one knows or even is interested in, perhaps it was discovered independently on several worlds by different species.
Perhaps similar to the question when and where in Terran history the wheel was invented and how it spread its way across the world.

Comment: *"The wheel was invented in Russia"* - Pavel Chekov ☺

Comment: LOL - I also remember a dispute between Chekov and Scotti about whether *Fool me once, shame on you, fool me twice, shame on me* was a Scottish or a Russian proverb. Seems Chekov is a bit possessive when it comes to claiming credit for inventions to his people :-)

Comment: The wheel is bit different. I can imagine a single person coming up with the wheel by themselves, but it's harder to imagine a single person coming up with FTL.

Comment: @Acccumulation You've obviously not read Niven's _Like Banquo's Ghost_.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf the Sovs were like that during the 1950s and 60s.

Comment: @Acccumulation How?  The wheel is extremely simple.  Surely stone-age people all over the world used log rollers.  Once you understand that rolling things is better than dragging things, it's not a huge leap in logic to attach those rollers to a sled.  Hyperspace drives seem a lot more complicated than logs.

Comment: @Ryan_L You've obviously not seen a hyperdrive in real life

Comment: @Ryan_L: many inventions are simple once they've already been invented. A simple wheel requires a pretty good amount of crafting to make work, and also is not very useful unless you have flat land to roll around on.

Comment: @whatsisname Pfff, just make the wheel bigger.

Comment: @Ryan_L You seem to have misread my comment.

Comment: @Ryan_L The wheel may be simple in retrospect, but some (all?) pre-columbian cultures in South America missed it (e.g. the Incas)